# fwrite putting error indicator on stream in C

Tags: c

In what cases does does the function fwrite put an error indicator onto the stream, such that ferror will return true?

Specifically, I am wondering if it puts an error when all the bytes were not successfully written.

Please provide a link as to where you get your information from.

Thank you

Comment: What are you talking about?  fwrite() returns size_t, not a bool.  You seem to get mixed up with `<iostream>`, a C++ header.

Comment: What compiler are you using? What OS?

Comment: @Hans: `fwrite` returns `size_t` but `ferror` returns a boolean value of type `int`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If any error occurs, the error indicator for the stream will be set, and will not be cleared until `clearerr` is called. However, due to buffering, it's difficult for stdio functions to report errors. Often the error will not be seen until a later call, since buffering data never fails, but the subsequent write after the buffer is full might fail. If you're using stdio to write files, the only ways I know to handle write errors robustly are (choose one):

- disable buffering (with `setbuf` or `setvbuf` - this must be the *very first* operation performed on the `FILE` after it's opened or otherwise it has UB)
- keep track of the last successful `fflush` and assume any data after that might be only partially-written
- treat any failed write as a completely unrecoverable file and just delete it

Also note that on a POSIX system, `fwrite` (and other stdio functions) are required to set `errno` to indicate the type of error, if an error occurs. As far as plain C is concerned, these functions may set `errno`, or they may not.

Comment: Would `fwrite()` fail if the error indicator was already set before calling it?

Comment: @Harith: No. While most error conditions are probably sticky anyway, some like `ENOSPC` can be transient.

Answer (score 0):

From the fwrite man page on my Linux system:

```
RETURN VALUE
   fread() and fwrite() return the number of items successfully read or written
   (i.e., not the number of characters).  If an error occurs, or the end-of-file
   is  reached, the return value is a short item count (or zero).

   fread()  does  not  distinguish between end-of-file and error, and callers
   must use feof(3) and ferror(3) to determine which occurred.
```

Just from reading the man page, it doesn't look like it will set `errno`.

Comment: Your conclusion is wrong. On Linux (which aims to conform to POSIX), `fwrite` **must** set `errno` on failure.

Comment: R, could you provide some documentation on where it says this? I need to try to make a point to someone.

Comment: R, if i have many subsequent calls to fwrite, is it sufficient to check if ferror is true at the very end?

Comment: `fwrite` is defined in terms of `fputc`, and its specification refers to `fputc` for errors. `fputc`'s specification (in POSIX) is here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fputc.html

Comment: And yes, once the error indicator is set for a stream, it is permanent until you call `clearerr` on the stream. So it's perfectly acceptable to check `ferror` at the end and ignore it up until then.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows `fwrite` may put error when try to write to read-opened stream.

For example if there was a call to `seekg` which sets read flag to the stream and `seekp` was not called before writing.